# Javascript: Set the order of functions

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a titanium app but I'm having an issue with the execution order of my javascript.

I have an event listener on a button. It's a reload button that clears a table, uses HTTPClient to GET a JSON array of 'appointments', saves each appointment, and refreshes a table list. The problem is I am executing the table delete first which should clear the table, then I get the appointments but when the app refreshes the datatable it's like it's doing it too soon and the new appointments haven't been saved yet because I'm getting an empty list. Now if I comment out the db.deleteAll line, each time I click reload the list is refreshed with the new (and existing) appointment data.

I need to make sure everything is done in order and only when the previous task is dfinished. So appointments.download() has to be executed AFTER db.DeleteAll and the list refresh has to be executed AFTER var allAppointments = db.All();

I think the problem is that the appointments.download() function has to make a HTTP GET call and then save the results and the other functions are not waiting until it's finished.

Here is the code:

```
btnReload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var affected = db.deleteAll();
    appointments.download();
    var allAppointments = db.all();
    Ti.API.info(allAppointments);
    appointmentList.setData(allAppointments);
});
```

Here are the functions that are being called:

db.deleteAll():

```
api.deleteAll = function(){
    conn.execute('DELETE FROM appointments');
    return conn.rowsAffected;
}
```

appointments.download():

```
var appointments = (function() {
    var api = {};
    api.download = function(){

        var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        xhr.onload = function()
        {
          var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          var dl = (data.length);
          for(i=0; i<dl;i++)
          {
            //p = addRow(data,i); // returns the **arr array 
            //Ti.API.info('Saving : '+data[i].first_name);
            var contact_name = data[i].first_name + ' ' + data[i].last_name;
            var start_date = data[i].start_date;
            var reference = data[i].reference;
            var comment = data[i].comment;
            var appointment_id = data[i].quote_id;

            var lastid = db.create(appointment_id, start_date, reference, contact_name, comment);
            //Ti.API.info(lastid);
          }

        };
        xhr.open('GET','http://********.co.uk/appointments/download/');
        xhr.send();

        return;
}
```

Any help most appreciated!
Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous calls give you coordination (code won't execute until any computation it depends on finishes) for free. With asynchronous calls, you have to take care of coordination. This generally means passing the dependent code as a function to the asynchronous code. The passed code is known as a "[continuation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/12/22/continuation-passing-style.aspx)", which means "the rest of the calculation, from a given point forward". Passing continuations around is known as (unsurprisingly) "[continuation passing style](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/cps/)".

To rewrite code in CPS, identify the point(s) where you need to coordinate the code (the call to `appointments.download`), then wrap the rest of the code in a function.

```
btnReload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var affected = db.deleteAll();
    appointments.download();
    function () {
        var allAppointments = db.all();
        Ti.API.info(allAppointments);
        appointmentList.setData(allAppointments);
    }
});
```

In the general case, the return value becomes the argument to the continuation. Here, no return value for `appointments.download` is used, so the continuation takes no arguments.

Next, rewrite the asynchronous function to take the continuation and pass the continuation in the call.

```
btnReload.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var affected = db.deleteAll();
    appointments.download(
        function () {
            var allAppointments = db.all();
            Ti.API.info(allAppointments);
            appointmentList.setData(allAppointments);
        });
});

...
api.download = function(_return){
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var dl = (data.length);
        for (i=0; i<dl;i++) {
            //p = addRow(data,i); // returns the **arr array 
            //Ti.API.info('Saving : '+data[i].first_name);
            var contact_name = data[i].first_name + ' ' + data[i].last_name;
            var start_date = data[i].start_date;
            var reference = data[i].reference;
            var comment = data[i].comment;
            var appointment_id = data[i].quote_id;

            var lastid = db.create(appointment_id, start_date, reference, contact_name, comment);
            //Ti.API.info(lastid);
        }
        _return();
    };
    xhr.open('GET','http://********.co.uk/appointments/download/');
    xhr.send();

    return;
}
```

The continuation is named `_return` because the `return` statement can be modeled as a continuation (the default continuation). Calling `_return` in the asynchronous version would have the same affect as calling `return` in the synchronous version.

Comment: Thanks outis! This worked really well and thanks for the description of CPS!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are making requests asynchronously which means you make a request and return from the function immediately, you don't wait for an answer. You should make your calls synchronous, I don't know what your `conn` and `xhr` really are but they might provide ways to make the `execute()` and `send()` methods synchronous. For example if you set the third argument of JavaScript's own `XMLHttpRequest`'s `open()` method to `false` then `send()` method will not return until a response is received from the server, your connection classes might have the same option.

Comment: Making the request synchronous is a bad idea. It will block all JS calls until the request completes. This can cause the browser UI to stop responding, giving the appearance that it's hung.

Answer (score 0):

Move the call to delete the current appointments into the onload handler. That way you will delete the old and immediately add the new data.